# Using Symfony's 2.3 NotEqualTo Constraint with an entity

Tags: php, symfony

I'm writing an application where an user can recommend other users and I need to avoid they recommend themselves, so I thought the [NotEqualTo](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotEqualTo.html) constraint, applied to a foreing key on the entity (An user is recommended by another) would do the trick. The problem is that it appears to accept only scalar values, instead of entities.

Does anyone have more information about this? Should I extend the constraint to do this?

Comment: What about [UniqueEntity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) ?

Comment: Will not work. I don't need to check for an unique primary key, what I need is to ensure the PK value is different from the foreing key on the same entity.

Comment: @danielperaza could you find the solution for your problem? I faced the same problem too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the [Callback](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) validator with a check like:

```php
if ($this->recommender == $this->recommendee) {
    // ...
}
```

Another way would be to create a [custom validation constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html).

Comment: Callback is a nice suggestion, but I was hoping to find an option on the constraint to do the trick while avoiding to code more lines.

Comment: I'll try it out and see what happens.